# Why i can't call container.findAll("h3", {"class":"name"})?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

What I want is just scrape all the products. Why I also can't use containers.div ? I really confused when there is `<div><\div><div>` while at my tutorial is just `<div></div>`.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://hbx.com/categories/sneakers'

# membuka koneksi, mengambil halaman
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# mengambil masing2 produk
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"product-wrapper col-xs-6 col-sm-4"})

filename = "kontol.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "judul, brand, harga\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    title_container = container.findAll("h3", {"class":"name"})
    judul = title_container[0].text

    brand_container = container.findAll("h4", {"class":"brand"})
    brand = brand_container[0].text

    price_container = container.findAll("span", {"class":"regular-price"})
    harga = price_container[0].text

    print("judul: " + judul)
    print("brand: " + brand)
    print("harga: " + harga)

    f.write(judul + "," + brand + "," + harga + "\n")

f.close()
```

When I trying call using container.findAll("h3", {"class":"name"}) I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1807, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: After running this code on my own computer it seems as though you are going to have some issues scraping this data from this site using urllib. It seems as though much of the content is rendered using javascript which will make it such that you will be unable to scrape it using urllib. I would suggest looking into using Selenium to solve this: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below script and tell me it didn't fix the issue. I used conditional statement to avoid any error supposed to happen if any item is none, as in the second result where price is none. Now it works great.

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://hbx.com/categories/sneakers"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text,"lxml")
for item in soup.find_all(class_="product-box"):
    name = item.find(class_="name").text if item.find(class_="name") else ""
    brand = item.find(class_="brand").text if item.find(class_="brand") else ""
    price = item.find(class_="regular-price").text if item.find(class_="regular-price") else ""
    print(name,brand,price)
```

Or with `find_all` if you like. However, the result are always the same.

```
for item in soup.find_all(class_="product-box"):
    name = item.find_all(class_="name")[0].text if item.find_all(class_="name") else ""
    brand = item.find_all(class_="brand")[0].text if item.find_all(class_="brand") else ""
    price = item.find_all(class_="regular-price")[0].text if item.find_all(class_="regular-price") else ""
    print(name,brand,price)
```

Partial result:

```
Club C 85 Reebok USD 75.00
NMD R2 Runner Primeknit Adidas Originals 
NMD R2 Runner Adidas Originals USD 155.00
```